# Multiple httplib implementations prevent catching HttpException on Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I use the GAE python SDK, and trying to catch HttpException.
When I test the code locally, and import the exception like this:

```
from httplib import HTTPException
```

The exception is not caught, because the SDK provide alternative httplib implementation which throws the exception. So I tried

```
from google.appengine.dist27.httplib import HTTPException
```

And it works locally, but I'm sure its not the right solution for production code. What is the best solution that will work both on production and locally?

Comment: How do you run your code in local?

Comment: And what's code that should raise exception.

Comment: The code is run using the GAE Launcher. The exception is thrown from `urllib2.urlopen(request)`

Comment: I am confused. Why do you wan t catch a httplib exception in a urllib2 call

Comment: urllib is implemented using httplib and raises an HTTPException on timeout.

Comment: But why don't you use urlfetch ?  Then the exception source is clear and consistent.

Comment: Good idea, I didn't really think about that, Thanks!

Comment: and urllib etc  all use urlfetch so unless you are using a lib that uses urllib(2) you should always work directly with urlfetch.